# How to create a script to split and rejoin words in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to write an Apps Script script in Google Sheets to split a cell containing words and re concatenate them in a different format. There may be any number of words in the input cell.

**Input in cell A1**: cat, dog, mouse, rat

**Output in cell B2** : "CAT", "DOG", "MOUSE", "RAT"

I cannot get the `for` loop correct

```
function tags(data) {
  array1 = data.split(", ");
  a =[]
  for (i=1; i<21; i++){
    a = a + char(34) + i + char(34)
    return a
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your script, I thought that you are using your script as a custom function. If my understanding is correct, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script 1:

When your script is modified, how about the following modification?

```
function tags(data) {
  var array1 = data.split(", ");
  var a = []
  for (var i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
    a.push(String.fromCharCode(34) + array1[i].toUpperCase() + String.fromCharCode(34));
  }
  return a.join(", ");
}
```

##### Modification points:

- `char(34)` cannot be directly used.
- `array1` is not used in your script.
- In your script, the for loop is stopped at the 1st loop by `return a`.

#### Modified script 2:

In order to achieve your goal, you can also the following modification.

```
function tags(data) {
  if (!Array.isArray(data)) data = [[data]];
  return data.map(r => r.map(c => c.split(",").map(e => `"${e.trim().toUpperCase()}"`).join(", ")));
}
```

- In this case, for example, you can use the custom function like `=tags(A1)`, `=tags(A1:A5)` and `=tags(A1:D5)`.

#### Note:

- From your question, I used `toUpperCase()`. If you don't want to use it, please remove it.

#### References:

- [Custom Functions in Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions)
- [fromCharCode()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode)
- [toUpperCase()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toUpperCase)

Answer (score 0):

```
function tags(data) {
  data = data.toUpperCase().split(",");

  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
    data[i] = ('"' + data[i] + '"');
  
  return data.join(", ");
}
```